# Tortoisehg inconsistently asks for password on Push to Bitbucket

Tags: repository, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I have Tortoisehg set up with a clone of a remote repository on Bitbucket, using https protocol. I turned on the mercurial_keyring extension, and it took care of password handling just fine. Until one day it didn't. Every time I commit now, on push-after-commit it pops up and asks me for a password.

I carefully changed the password on the server, and started typing in that password when asked. IT DOESN'T HELP! It doesn't accept that password.
I hit cancel when asked for the password. Then I go and press the Push green arrow button at the top right of the screen. After asking for confirmation – IT GOES! No password required!

There are three computers that connect to this particular Bitbucket repository. For a while two of the three were working fine without asking a password. Then another one started asking! And then a third popped up asking for something different: "You need to identify yourself to the server." Once again, cancel, use the Push button, works fine!

I am so confused. Has anyone seen this, has anyone fixed it?

BTW, the remote repository is nowhere mentioned in my tortoisehg settings, but it is in my hgrc file:

```
[paths]
default = https://joymaker3@bitbucket.org/joymaker3/my-repo-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I yjink, you have to re-read at least section 3.2. "[Repository configuration (HTTP)](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension#Repository_configuration_.28HTTP.29)" of extension wiki and check related settings of all repos:

- good (full) URL in `[paths]`
- only needed data (*if* needed) in `[auth]` (no password for configured remote repository)

you can also enable debug in TortoiseHG and inspect output on failed push

Comment: Lazy Badger, do I read you correctly that I should just use hgrc  and ignore the numerous configuration options in Tortoise?

Comment: @Joymaker - both needed section are *more relevant* inside per-repository .hgrc, Global Configuration Editor doesn't have these sections in it's GUI, **but** you can easy edit per-repository configuration from the same context-menu (2) https://pastenow.ru/61VEV